# How to prevent Stackoverflow Exception in HtmlAgilityPack for very bad html

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack in an MVC 5 Web Api.  99.99% of the time, there are no problems... sites load and I parse them to extract the text I want.  My API could be hit several hundred thousand times a day without issues.  It has happily handled over 2 million hits in 24 hours in the past...

Occasionally however, terribly formed websites cause an error 500 response.  Then all subsequent requests get 500 errors and the site becomes completely unusable. The only solution in this scenario is to restart the web application.  The site is hosted on Windows Azure. I have used load balanced Large instances and once CPU spikes it stays high.  In the past, this has run fine on a single Medium Azure instance (2 core/3.5 GB RAM)

The error is a Stackoverflow... which I know I cannot catch.

Note, that this code does NOT crash a Console application

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://nursingandmidwiferycareersni.com/");            
Console.Write(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
```

...but it definitely will crash an MVC web app.

However, in a simple MVC web application, I can reproduce the stackoverflow error with a site such as http://nursingandmidwiferycareersni.com/.  If you put http://nursingandmidwiferycareersni.com/ into https://validator.w3.org  You will manage to get an Internal Server Error on validator.w3.org!

I will make a hack to HAP source code if necessary to get around this... at present I am just using the Nuget package.

Is it possible to prevent the stackoverflow happening in HAP?
Or is there a way of checking for awful html and preventing the crash from occurring in the first place?

Comment: My first thought is to simply keep a blacklist of sites that have malformed HTML.

Comment: You could also try parsing untrusted HTML on its own thread, and then using `Thread.Abort` to kill it if it ever takes longer than some timeout to parse some HTML.

Comment: I tried to look at source of the page in chrome, just out of curiosity, chrome itself is having serious issues to [view the source](view-source:http://nursingandmidwiferycareersni.com/). This site has 211.023 lines - most of it seems to be a white space.

Comment: @TimothyShields I have managed to crash Chrome by viewing source. Unfortunately your suggestion to keep a blacklist of sites will be impossible - I could have millions of new domains to scan using HAP.  As for aborting a thread, this is an option but not my preferred approach. I currently have a timeout on the web request of 6000ms.

Answer (score 1):

Give something like this a try, where the `ParseHtml` method and the `ParsedHtml` type are just placeholders for you to fill in:

```
public async Task<ParsedHtml> TryParseHtml(
    string untrustedHtml,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ParsedHtml>();

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        ParsedHtml result = ParseHtml(untrustedHtml);
        tcs.TrySetResult(result);
    });
    thread.Start();

    using (cancellationToken.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled()))
    {
        try
        {
            return await tcs.Task;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            thread.Abort();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea could be extended to be more efficient by reusing threads in the successful case, rather than firing up and tearing down a thread for every HTML page.

Comment: Note that `StackOverflowException` crashes the process, and given the right HTML it could happen in an instant.  So short of spawning a new process you always have a chance of your current process crashing.